# __block variable not retained

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to assign results within a block to a block variable. Here's my code:

```
__block UIImage *latestImage;
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

// Enumerate just the photos and videos group by using ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos.
[assetLibrary   enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos 
                              usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop){
                                  // Within the group enumeration bl  ock, filter to enumerate just photos.
                                  [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];

                                  // Chooses the photo at the last index
                                  [group  enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:([group numberOfAssets]-1)] 
                                                           options:0
                                                        usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop){   
                                                            // the end of the enumeration is signaled by asset == nil.
                                                            if (alAsset){
                                                                ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];
                                                                latestImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullResolutionImage]];
                                                            }
                                                        }];
                              }
                            failureBlock: ^(NSError *error){
                                // handle error
                                NSLog(@"No groups");
                            }
 ];
return latestImage;
```

I confirmed that the variable latestImage was set within the block, by displaying it on a UIImageView from inside the block. However, when I try to return that object as shown in the code above, it returns nothing.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:` is asynchronous. You're returning latestImage before the block has had a chance to set the variable. From the documentation on ALAssestsLibrary:

> Many of the methods declared by ALAssetsLibrary take a failure block
>   as an argument. These methods are all asynchronous, because the user
>   may need to be asked to grant access to the data.

You can either wrap the whole function in a `dispatch_sync()` or use a semaphore to wait for the answer. Either way, make sure you're not doing this on the main thread.